# Joomla To do list Extension

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla-module

Is there any Joomla Extension that allows any registered user to keep a list of their To-do items with the
following attributes;
1. Title
2. Date due
3. Description.
In the entry form, the Title should be a Text field, the Date due should be the pop-up calendar found in
the Joomla API and the Description should use the default WYSIWIG editor in the Joomla Installation.

I have searched for this particular extension or any that is close to this but to no avail.Please help.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to be asking for extension recommendations. Go on the Joomla Extensions Directory site and see what you can find there

Comment: Try this - http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=task+list

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create that component yourself using the [Joomla Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/).

Answer (score 0):

I found this question as I was looking for the exact same thing: recommendation for extension that supports developer/admin communication and task tracking.  Joomla Extensions Directory has neither a forum nor Q&A structure.  It would be nice if this kind of question was encouraged here.